# Text align left but div center

Tags: html, iphone, center, text-align

I want to make a list that is left aligned, but I want the block to be centered on the page.
Since I don't have the width because the size is different when watched on iPhone's Safari, it's very hard to do it and I have no idea of how...
Thank you!

```
<center>
 <div style="width:;text-align:center;margin:0 auto 1em auto;border:1px solid white;padding:0cm 0.5cm 0cm 12%">
  <p style="text-align:left;">
   <b>1.</b> text one<br>
      <font size="1"> &nbsp; &nbsp; small sub</font><br><br>
   <b>2.</b> text two is longer because he think it's very cool to stand out but hey everything is alright<br><br>
   <b>3.</b> three is a tree<br><br>
   <b>4.</b> four means nothing<br><br>
   <b>5.</b> short<br><br>
         <center>fake center text with padding</center>
  </p>
 </div><br><br>
     real center text
</center>
```

Comment: Which block exactly do you want to be centered ?

Comment: The div, but I give up. Just used another temporal method

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to make a list, I would first use the [ol tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) (ordered list) instead of a p tag with a bunch of break tags. And then if the list is contained within a div or block element (block element spans the full width of the window) you can center the block element by giving it a width and in the css give it margin: 0 auto; . This would mean that you're telling the computer to give it equal margins to the left and right. Make sure to give the element you're centering a width though, or else margin: 0 auto won't work.

If you're not sure of the width, decide on how much of the screen you want the centered element to take (ie: 50%, 90%, etc.). Hope that helps!

```
<div id="center">
 <ol>
   <li>text one</li>
   <li>text two</li>
   <li>three is a tree</li>
   <li>four means nothing</li>
   <li>short</li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#centered{
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to change everything and code it to get the numbers bold. I went for another option by now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>head,body{font-family:ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:black} a{color:white;} 
.mobile{width:635px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;padding:0.3cm 0cm 0.5cm 2%;}
.mobiles{width:65%;text-align:center;margin:0 auto 1em auto;border:1px solid white;padding:0.1cm 0.3cm 0cm 3%;}
 @media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:568px)
  {.mobile{width:100%;padding:0.5cm 0cm 0.5cm 2%
   .mobiles{width:auto;text-align:center;margin:0 auto 1em auto;border:1px solid white;padding:0cm 0.5cm;}
  ;}</style>

<div class="mobiles"><p class="mobile">
```